# Expanding list not moving footer after dynamic content load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I previously asked a similar question and the fix worked, however it has now stopped working for some reason. Essentially i'm developing a website you can find [here](http://drue.co.uk/1site/index.html) along with the stylesheet [here](http://drue.co.uk/1site/style.css) and the javascript file [here](http://drue.co.uk/1site/js/scripts.js).

You'll notice that when initially on the index page and expanding an element the footer/container's height gets modified accordingly, however when you navigate to a different page using the left-sidebar and going back to the top-rated page, when expanding an element, the footer/container does not get modified and stays static. Any ideas on what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an idea, not sure why but this seems to stem from the way you link to the homepage:

http://drue.co.uk/1site/index.html - works

http://drue.co.uk/1site/index.html#index.html - doesn't work

The hashbang method of ajax page loads is generally considered bad practise, so I would recommend either looking into the [history api](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html) and seeing if you encounter the same problem, or simply just linking straight to the homepage from other pages, whilst this will result in the whole page re-rendering, the page is relatively small (about 250kb on load) so this shouldn't be a massive issue (most of the homepage will likely already be cached by the browser)

EDIT:

for some reason, when navigating to the page via the second url, the `div` with an ID of `inside`

```
<div id="inside" style="height: 367px;">
```

It seems that this is incorporated into your JS for the ajax pageloads (after the page has loaded the height of the div is set presumably so the page displays correctly)

I would recommend removing this from your JavaScript and using some for of clearfix on the inside div, e.g. using `overflow: hidden` or any number of [other methods](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/)